# RAM usage alert by log analytics | Azure

Tags: azure, monitoring, alert

I have trying to set up alerts on VM RAM usage with 80% threshold but I failed on finding out the 'query' which works.

Resource (data source) of the alert is a 'log analytics workspace' where I have performance data from multiple machines.

Right now, my query looks that:

```
Perf
| where CounterName == "% Used Memory"
| summarize AggregatedValue = avg(CounterValue) by bin(TimeGenerated, 5m), Computer
```

[my setting screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VLSe.png)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are very close, just mixed up the last bit.

Try this:

```
Perf
| where  CounterName == "% Used Memory"
| summarize AggregatedValue = avg(CounterValue) by Computer, bin(TimeGenerated, 5m)
```

The threshold of 80% should be added in the configuration of the alert.